# copy files recursively using batch script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I have this code to copy files recursively from one folder to another.

```
set COMP_PATH=C:\Users\bose\Documents\test-download

cd C:\Users\bose\Desktop\downloaddir_nec
for /R %%f in (*.*) do copy /y %%f %COMP_PATH%
cd ..
```

This works fine as long as the folders I am recursing through don't have **commas** in them.
I get this output when the folders have commas:
[image]

How do I fix this? I want to copy the contents of all folders, recursively.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any good reason why you want to make this simple task that complicated? xcopy.exe or robocopy.exe (both Windows standard commandline tools) can easily copy folder trees by just one call.

Comment: One line in a batch file: ```@For /R "%UserProfile%\Desktop\downloaddir_nec" %%G in (*) Do @Copy /Y "%%G" "%UserProfile%\Documents\test-download"```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the path in double quotes.

```
 set COMP_PATH=C:\Users\bose\Documents\test-download
    cd C:\Users\bose\Desktop\downloaddir_nec
    for /R %%f in (.) do copy /y "%%f" "%COMP_PATH%"
    cd ..
```